# C# - Passing a inherited class through a parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, methods, parameters

I have a scenario in which I would like to be able to pass a class through a methods parameter and get class specific information from the instance of the class that was passed.

Example:

```
public abstract class Foo {
   public int x;
}
```

Then

```
public class Bar : Foo {
    public int y;
    public Bar(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is something like this

```
public void foobar(Foo f) {
    int y = f.y;
}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
foobar(new Bar(5));
```

This would be getting a value that is specific to the class "Bar" which "Inherits" from the class Foo.

I need to be able to do this without typcasting, so that the class will be handled dynamically.

I know that I can just say

```
((Bar)f).y
```

However, the point is I will have multiple classes being passed through and typecasting statically will defeat the purpose.

Comment: Why not define y in Foo then?  Especially if you are going to try to get at a y value in any inherited class.

Comment: But it defeats the object-oriented programming. Cant you prepare interface, f.e IBar with `y` property?

Comment: Have a look at this link of the MSDN at the paragraph "Identifier Patterns": http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd547125.aspx . It's in F# and not C# but I guess this is what you want to achieve. If you would like a can post some C# code accomplishing the same as the F# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't break OOP rules. So here is one of solutions:

```
public interface IBar
{
    int Y { get; }
}

public Bar : Foo, IBar { ... }

public void foobar(IBar f) {
    int y = f.Y;
}
```

But if you really want to, you can:

use dynamic:

```
public void foobar(Foo f) 
{
    dynamic df = (dynamic)f;
    int y;
    try
    {
       y = df.y;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
       // case when foo doesn't have a y
    }
}
```

or reflection:

```
public void foobar(Foo f) 
{
    var type = f.GetType();
    var field = type.GetFields(BindigFlags.Instance 
                                | BindigFlags.Public)
                      .FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == "y");

    if (field == null)
    {
       // case when f doesn't have a field
    }

    int y = (int)field.GetValue(f);
}
```

Comment: The interface solution wouldn't work (From the way I understand it), because I could have class "Foo : Bar" that has the variable y, then another class "Jim : Bar" that would have the variable q, but not y. Each class won't have the same variables, it completely depends on the class. The dynamic keyword is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do with your design is impossible. One way that comes to mind - define abstract method in `Foo` and all the inherited classes will override this method. This method will return `y` (or other information from other derived classes).

```
public abstract class Foo {
   public int x;
   public abstract int GetValue();
}

public class Bar : Foo 
{
  private int y;
  public Bar(int y) 
  {
    this.y = y;
  }
  public override int GetValue()
  {
     return y;
  }
}
```

Then you can retrieve value like this

```
public void foobar(Foo f) {
    int y = f.GetValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by duck typing, please refer to this link: [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

this can be done in C# by using dynamic keyword.